# How to extract analytics from Adobe at URL filtered by channel using R

Tags: r, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to extract URL level data in a filtered channel (organic search) using the Adobe Analytics API and it's failing. How do I make it work?

I've tried using the RSiteCatalyst in R using the following code:

```
  QueueDataWarehouse(my_rsid,
                     date.from = "2019-06-01",
                     date.to = "2019-06-30",
                     segment.id = "s300007365_5b366bb3f30aae698e8b0488",
                     elements = c("entrypage"),
                     metrics = c("uniquevisitors","averagetimespentonpage", "event123", "event38"),
                     enqueueOnly = F)
```

I expected a dataframe as defined in the code above and instead I get a dataframe that is NULL.

Please help.

PS While I'm here, is there another R package to work with the newer version of the API being 2.0?

Comment: Have you tried extracting data without segment or filter to see if there is any return?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I get a return. In the end I worked it out. I had to create a segment in the Interface, grab the segment.id name and then use it in the api call.